# Odoo 10 - Overloading a Python Method

Tags: python, odoo

I have a question. I have a function that is called overloading the write () method.
I have another function that has nothing to do but it modifies fields.

Except that it necessarily calls the write method that calls the first function ...

Is there a way for the write method to not be called when certain fields are affected?

Here is my code:

Write () method:

```
# Appel cette méthode quand on modifie un enregistrement
    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        result = super(ResPartnerSchool, self).write(vals)
        self.no_duplicate_school_dates()
        if not self.env.context.get('tracking_disable'):
            self.smart_synchronization()
        return result
```

smart_synchronization() method :

```
@api.multi
def smart_synchronization(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.school_statut == "valid":
            record.create_compte_in_smart()
            if record.school_send_onde and record.school_date_status == fields.Date.today():
                record.prepare_files_for_onde()
```

The method prepar_files_to_ONDE is called when I use this method:

```
# Méthode CRON pour fermetures contrats à une date saisie par l'agent
    @api.model
    def run_close_old_contracts(self):
        _logger.info("CRON Called for to verify closed dates contracts")
        today = fields.Date.today()
        domain = ['|', '|', ("half_pension_unsubscribe", "=", True),
                            ("nursery_morning_unsubscribe", "=", True),
                            ("nursery_evening_unsubscribe", "=", True)]
        for contract in self.search(domain):
            vals = {}
            if contract.school_registration >= today <= contract.school_end_date:
                if contract.half_pension_unsubscribe \
                        and contract.half_pension_unsubscribe_date <= today \
                        and contract.half_pension_status == "2":
                    vals["half_pension_status"] = "3"
                    _logger.info("Contract half pension closed for : " + contract.partner_id.name)
                if contract.nursery_morning_unsubscribe \
                        and contract.nursery_morning_unsubscribe_date <= today \
                        and contract.nursery_status_morning == "2":
                    vals["nursery_status_morning"] = "3"
                    _logger.info("Contract nursery morning closed for : " + contract.partner_id.name)
                if contract.nursery_evening_unsubscribe \
                        and contract.nursery_evening_unsubscribe_date <= today \
                        and contract.nursery_status_evening == "2":
                    vals["nursery_status_evening"] = "3"
                    _logger.info("Contract nursery evening closed for : " + contract.partner_id.name)
                if vals:
                    contract.write(vals)
```

It is at this level that my methods of the write () methods are called. Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes of course, the second param 'vals' contains fields to edit

Comment: Do you want to not call python method for certain fiedls right ?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you update a field on a record, assume the `write` function is going to be called. This is built into the Odoo ORM.

For example, if I grab a record from the database.

```
partner = env['res.partner'].browse(1)
```

And then I update any fields on this partner record, it's going to call the `write` function to set them:

```
# these each will call `write` at some point
partner.name = 'abc'
partner.update({'street1': 'My Street'})
```

I highly recommend reading through the basic ORM methods in the `class BaseModel` definition in the core repository (`odoo/models.py`). Going through `unlink`, `write`, `_write`, `update`, `create`, etc. gives you a better grasp on what's going on behind the scenes.

Of course, reading through the [official ORM docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html) doesn't hurt either.